# Cisco 1921 router stops routing traffic

Tags: cisco, router, nat

I have a cisco 1921 router that recently started acting up. I haven't changed anything on the router in many months because everything was running smoothly, until a week ago.

Configuration: The setup is pretty basic. The router has one port attached to the ISP over ethernet with a 8 port EHWIC ethernet switch which are used as access ports for workstations. The router is using DHCP, CBAC, NAT, and ACLs. There is only one vlan, one public IP, and one private network. The vlan interface is the gateway for private network. CBAC is used to inspect traffic from the private network to the internet. No services are allowed from the outside.

Symptoms: After the router starts up, everyone can access the internet as usual. Eventually, the router stops all traffic. During this blocking state, no workstation can ping the gateway. I am able to access the console and it works fine. From the console, I am able to ping all the IPs for all router interfaces, and pings work through CBAC, but can not ping out of any interface to any workstation or ISP gateway. Restarting the router fixes the problem for a short period of time. I am able to replicate the problem by doing a speed test or download a large file. After about 50ish mb transfer, the blocking state happens.

Troubleshooting steps:

Disabled CBAC and ACLs.
Verified no memory errors.
Verified there is plenty of free memory.
Debugged NAT, no errors.
Upgraded IOS to latest (15.4.3)
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to enable logs and see what's there?

Comment: Does the time between failure vary, or is it constant? I once had a 1921 have a problem exactly 4 hours after reboot which helped narrow it down to an arp problem. Might be worth posting a cleansed version of your config.

Comment: Hardware problem, or something trigger a bad state in the router. A packet capture on the inside interface ?

Comment: ARP and CAM table utilization would be my guess as well. Routers can be used as small switches, but they aren't architected that way. Do you just have one client workstation on each port of the EHWIC?

Comment: @Navern, the logs don't provide many details. Only information about boot up and no errors.

Comment: @ChadH360, the time of failure seems to completely depend on how much data has been transferred/NAT'ed. More data, quicker failure.

Comment: @Alo, I have a another switch, and WLAN AP on a couple of switchports. Other ports have a couple of servers, last ones are used as workstation access ports. If its a design issue, I wounder what would have triggered a problem after such a long time...

Comment: @yagmoth555, I'll turn on packet capture and report back. Any specific debug commands that may help? Any other ways to narrow down if its a hardware issue?

Comment: @JoshMardis don't happen to have another 1921 that can you can apply same config to rule out the router ? as no config change, and now the router act that way, it's strange

Comment: Did more troubleshooting. The issue is with the EHWIC (EHWIC-D-8ESG-P=). I verified this by enabling the other router port g0/1, gave it an IP, added it to the zone and attached an external switch to it. Now everything is working fine. Any way to get detailed diags for the card? What about updating firmware?